# Rhythmbox 2.99.1 in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, rhythmbox

I've tried installing Rhythmbox 2.99.1 using the .tar.xz from saucy on launchpad and I seem to be getting errors about dependencies. Does anyone know a good way to fix these dependencies issues?

I tried installing it agian with extra instructions and here is what I got. Note that the terminal cut off me cding, extracting.

```
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/it/it.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-toolbar-repeat.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-toolbar-shuffle.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/el.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/el/el.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/cs.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/cs/cs.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/zh_CN.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/zh_CN.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-toolbar-repeat.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-toolbar-shuffle.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/zh_CN/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/de.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-toolbar-repeat.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-toolbar-shuffle.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/de/de.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-toolbar-repeat.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-notification-zone.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-toolbar-shuffle.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/C/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/da.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/da.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/da/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/sv.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/sv.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sv/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/gl.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/gl.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/gl/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/es.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/es/es.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ChangeLog
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/eu.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/eu.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-toolbar-repeat.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-notification-zone.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-toolbar-shuffle.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/eu/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/ro.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ro/ro.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/Makefile.am
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/fr.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-toolbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-window-small.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-volume-changer.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-statusbar.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-toolbar-prevplaynext.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-notification-zone.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-notification-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-podcast-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-iradio-main.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-notification-area-menu.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/figures/rb-window.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/fr/fr.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/pt.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/pt.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/pt/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/sl.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/sl.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/sl/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/ja.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/ja/ja.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/fdl-appendix.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/legal.xml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/oc.stamp
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/oc.po
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/oc/index.docbook
rhythmbox-2.99.1/help/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/configure
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/Makefile.am
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/rhythmbox-sections.txt
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/rhythmbox-overrides.txt
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-removable-media-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-shell-clipboard.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-tree-dnd.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-playlist-manager.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-song-info.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source-toolbar.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-entry-view.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-query-creator.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-device-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmbox-unused.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-import-job.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page-list.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page-tree.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-property-model.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-ext-db-key.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-fading-image.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source-search.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-library-browser.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-player.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-library-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-media-player-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-query-result-list.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-application.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-alert-dialog.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/mediaplayerid.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-static-playlist-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-play-queue-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-shell-player.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-async-queue-watch.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-stock-icons.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-encoder.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-shell-preferences.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-gst-media-types.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-auto-playlist-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source-header.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-search-entry.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-play-order-random.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-dialog.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-history.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-debug.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source-search-basic.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-ext-db.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-sourcelist.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-text-helpers.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-query-results.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-missing-files-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-async-copy.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-query-model.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-player-gst-tee.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-rating-helper.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-header.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-uri-dialog.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-source-group.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-metadata.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-browser-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-shell.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-file-helpers.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-segmented-bar.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-property-view.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-sourcelist-model.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-track-transfer-batch.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-string-value-map.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-track-transfer-queue.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-streaming-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-import-errors-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rhythmdb-entry-type.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-cell-renderer-pixbuf.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-rating.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-removable-media-manager.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page-model.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-util.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-refstring.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-transfer-target.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-play-order.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-player-gst-data-tee.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-builder-helpers.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-chunk-loader.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-cell-renderer-rating.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page-group.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-playlist-source.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-button-bar.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-statusbar.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-display-page-menu.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/tmpl/rb-player-gst-filter.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/rhythmbox.types
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBCellRendererRating.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBHeader.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBMissingFilesSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-tree-dnd.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch02.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBMetaData.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDB.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBDisplayPageModel.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBLibrarySource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayer.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDBQueryResults.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBMediaPlayerSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-ext-db-key.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-debug.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBRemovableMediaManager.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-builder-helpers.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch01.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayerGstFilter.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBShellClipboard.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBStaticPlaylistSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-util.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBAutoPlaylistSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-RBExtDB.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBImportErrorsSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBCellRendererPixbuf.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayerGstTee.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDBEntryType.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBURIDialog.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBShellPlayer.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch06.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBLibraryBrowser.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBStreamingSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch07.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayerGstDataTee.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDBQueryModel.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-RBEncoder.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDBImportJob.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBRating.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBStringValueMap.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RhythmDBPropertyModel.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBDisplayPage.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-gst-media-types.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-rating-helper.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch03.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBShell.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBSearchEntry.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/left.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/up.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-file-helpers.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBApplication.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch04.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-async-queue-watch.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/style.css
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayQueueSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/index.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox.devhelp2
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlaylistSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-text-helpers.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlaylistManager.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-rb-dialog.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBShellPreferences.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBQueryCreator.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBBrowserSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBStatusbar.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBDisplayPageGroup.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/index.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-RBDeviceSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBDisplayPageTree.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBTrackTransferBatch.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBEntryView.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPlayOrder.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/rhythmbox-RBTransferTarget.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBSongInfo.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBPropertyView.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/home.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBTrackTransferQueue.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBHistory.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBRandomPlayOrder.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/RBSource.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/right.png
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/html/ch05.html
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/rhythmbox-docs.sgml
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/Makefile.am
rhythmbox-2.99.1/doc/reference/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rhythmbox-set-star-inline.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-async-copy.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-udev.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-files.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-hal.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-dummy.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-private.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-util.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mpid-device.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/Makefile.am
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/libmediaplayerid/mediaplayerid.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-cut-and-paste-code.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-gst-media-types.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-async-queue-watch.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-util.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-marshal.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-missing-plugins.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-cut-and-paste-code.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-missing-plugins.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-string-value-map.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-async-copy.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-debug.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/eggdesktopfile.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-builder-helpers.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/eggdesktopfile.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-stock-icons.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rhythmbox-no-star-inline.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-util.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-marshal.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-chunk-loader.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-file-helpers.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/Makefile.am
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rhythmbox-unset-star-inline.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-chunk-loader.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-stock-icons.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-marshal.list
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-tree-dnd.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-text-helpers.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-debug.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-gst-media-types.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-string-value-map.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-async-queue-watch.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-text-helpers.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-tree-dnd.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/Makefile.in
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-builder-helpers.h
rhythmbox-2.99.1/lib/rb-file-helpers.c
rhythmbox-2.99.1/install-sh
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src$ cd rhythmbox-2.99.1/
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gobject-introspection : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (= 1.33.14-1) but 1.34.0+git20121017.aa4f3c70-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
 libbrasero-media3-dev : Depends: libbrasero-media3-1 (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.1-0ubuntu2~ubuntu12.10.1 is to be installed
 libclutter-1.0-dev : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (= 1.12.0-0ubuntu1) but 1.12.2-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
                      Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.10) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libcogl-dev (>= 1.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libcogl-pango-dev (>= 1.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev (>= 7.1~rc3-1~)
 libclutter-gst-dev : Depends: libclutter-gst-1.0-0 (= 1.6.0-1) but 1.6.1~git20120925.c7adcda3-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (= 1.3.2-0ubuntu1) but 1.4.0-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
 libgirepository1.0-dev : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (= 1.33.14-1) but 1.34.0+git20121017.aa4f3c70-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
                          Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0 (= 1.33.14-1) but 1.34.0+git20121017.aa4f3c70-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
                          Depends: gir1.2-freedesktop (= 1.33.14-1) but 1.34.0+git20121017.aa4f3c70-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.34.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.34.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.34.0-1ubuntu1) but 2.34.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgpod-dev : Depends: libgpod4 (= 0.8.2-6build1) but 0.8.2-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
               Depends: libgtk2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libimobiledevice-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (= 0.10.36-1ubuntu1) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                                     Depends: gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 (= 0.10.36-1ubuntu1) but 0.10.36-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.6.0-0ubuntu3) but 3.6.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.10.2 is to be installed
                Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 (= 3.6.0-0ubuntu3) but 3.6.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu12.10.2 is to be installed
                Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.30.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libpeas-dev : Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (= 1.4.0-2ubuntu3) but 1.6.1-0ubuntu1~quantal1 is to be installed
               Depends: gir1.2-peas-1.0 (= 1.4.0-2ubuntu3) but 1.6.1-0ubuntu1~quantal1 is to be installed
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (= 1.10.0-0ubuntu1) but 1.10.0-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0 (= 1.10.0-0ubuntu1) but 1.10.0-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-dev (= 1.10.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu7) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for rhythmbox could not be satisfied.
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gobject-introspection... configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ sudo make install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
david@david-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/src/rhythmbox-2.99.1$ ^C
```

EDIT

So if I chose to installl from .deb and then run `sudo apt-get -f install`
 will that install all the dependencies for Rhythmbox 2.99.1?

EDIT

The answer by `rajagenupula` doesn't work. It just downgrades Rhythmbox. I can't put the terminal log in here but its available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7133595/

Comment: what error  you are getting?

Comment: @AvinashRaj But wouldn't that get the dependencies for RB 2.97? I'm currently using RB 2.98 that I got from the Gnome-Shell testing ppa so it could also get dependencies for RB 2.98. I will try though, just let me clone my VM

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you post `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Make sure that, in Software Sources, your main, universe, multiverse, and restricted repos are checked and under "updates" you don't have pre-released updates checked.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 I'm running 12.10 (quantal) just like in the title

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically install all the build dependencies with `sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox`.

`apt-get build-dep <packagename>` works with any package you want to build from source. Simply name the package and all the packages you need to build it will automatically be installed.

Comment: OK I will try when my I finish cloning my VM. So this will work even with installing newer versions?

Comment: Doesn't work :(. I put the terminal log in the Q.

Answer (score -1):

Dependencies generally can fix by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: That only works for stock versions of the app. Will not work when installing newer versions of the app

Comment: ???? have you tried ?

Comment: see , you try it. required dep's you can get from it.